# Collect SNMP data from on-prem assets and send it to Azure log management

Tags: debian, azure, snmp, collectd, oms

I want to collect SNMP data from my on-prem equipment and send it to Azure log management.
To be more precise, I have a Linux virtual machine running in Azure that is to collect SNMP data from my on-prem router and send that data to my Azure log analytics workspace.
Is there any generally recommended and lightweight solution to this?

I was trying to achieve this using collectd, but the problem was connecting it with the OMS agent.
The collectd is to collect the SNMP data and forward it to OMS agent which then sends the data to Azure.

Now, I have a newly installed Debian 11 virtual machine. I have installed OMS agent, and collectd 5.12.0. that I have downloaded from collectd.org.
I cannot run the collectd service. The error I get is that there is a missing plugin called "write_http" which is necessary to connect it with the OMS agent (the .so file is missing, but the configuration regarding the plugin exists within the collectd.conf file).
So far I couldn't find that plugin to download it. Am I missing something?

I was wondering if someone could give me a detailed explanation/solution how to set this up from the beginning?

Thanks in advance!